# Stretch page width of the application

Tags: facebook, resize, width

I need to stretch width of the used space of my app. The following image shows that there is space to be used.

Image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/imgbe.png/

An example of this action would be:
http://apps.facebook.com/meucalendario/

Ps: I tried using: FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow, FB.Canvas.setSize () but no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it. It's max value is 760px, that is up-to how far you can stretch your application's view port.

Comment: Alright, you can do it for only canvas based application and you can use the full width of the page by setting the canvas width as fluid. You can find details and how to do that from this Facebook Developer Blog article http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/

Answer (score 2):

The Default Canvas Width is **760px**, but Facebook has recently added the option for developers to use *fluid* widths. Which means your iframe will have a `100%` width and will expand depending on the user's screen resolution/browser.

You can read the official blog post [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/), and an example (*assuming you already set the option in your app settings*):

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Fluid Width HTML Example </title>
 </head>

 <body style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0; background-color:#000000">

     <div id="allContent" style="background-color: #0000FF; height:100%">
        <div id="output" style="color: #FFFFFF;" />
     </div>

     <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     FB.init({
            appId  : 'APP ID',
        });

     function echoSize() {
              document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
                 "HTML Content Width: " + window.innerWidth + 
                 " Height: " + window.innerHeight;
              console.log(window.innerWidth + ' x ' + window.innerHeight);
        }

       echoSize();
       window.onresize = echoSize;
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*P.S.: You **can't** override the live ticker on the right!*